# The conditions for Newton's method in optimization to converge

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics

I want to use Newton's method to minimize $$ f(x) = c^T x - \sum_{i=1}^m \log(a_i^T x + b_i) $$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m_+,$ and $A=[\; a_1 \; \cdots \; a_m \;]^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, m>n.$

However, the program is not always converge.

Is there any condition on $A$, $b$, and $c$ can guarantee the convergence of Newton's method?

Comment: Is this the full optimization problem? No extra parameter $\mu$ that an interior point method has?

Comment: Actually, this is an unconstrained optimization problem.

Comment: Are you using a line search? Because it should converge without a problem. The objective is a self concordant function.

Comment: Yes, I perform backtracking line search along search direction. I also notice that the diverge cases are those problems that are unbounded below by using cvx toolbox in MATLAB.

Comment: Well, you cannot expect Newton's method to converge when the optimization problem has no optimal solution.

Comment: What condition could guarantee that the problem has an optimal solution?